# How to call out @media in Additional CSS?

Tags: css

Alright, so, I'm hoping this is an easy question, but I can't for the life of me get it working.

The situation:

1. I've made some changes in the Additional CSS portion of the customize feature on my Wordpress theme.
2. I've taught myself a few things, and I was able to edit the margins and whatnot of the footer widgets.
3. They look great on desktop, not so much on mobile.

From research, I've found that you can call out @media criteria, theoretically making two sets of margin settings: one for a max screen size you set for mobile, and one for desktop.

Here's what I've been able to come up with:

```
#text-5 .widget-title{
    margin:0px 0px 10px 0px}
#text-6 .widget-title{
    margin:0px 0px 10px 0px}
#text-7 .widget-title{
    margin:0px 0px 10px 0px}
#custom_html-2 .widget-title{
    margin:0px 0px 10px 0px}
#text-7 .footer-row-2-widget.widget.widget_text{
    width: 100px;}
#text-7 {
    width: 200px;
    margin:-10px 0px 5px -10px}
#text-5 {
    width: 200px;
    margin:-10px 0px 5px 0px}
#text-6 {
    width: 300px;
    margin:-10px 0px 5px -50px}
#custom_html-2 {
    width: 350px;
    margin:-10px 0px 5px -50px}
```

This seems to be working so far. (I know negative pixels is not ideal, but I can't figure out how to otherwise move the columns to where I want them.)

So, how do I call out @media in the Additional CSS? Nothing I'm finding is helping to show what needs to be done for the Additional CSS box itself, but rather for the editor files, which I don't want to touch (aka break).

Thank you!

The site in question: http://q6q.118.myftpupload.com/

Comment: Also, why did someone give this a thumbs down? I didn't realize my question was thumbs-down worthy. :|

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the media queries to you css file. Basically they are organized for breakpoints in pixels depending of the screen size, which will apply the rules it has inside.

Here are some of the most common breakpoints (you can make your own to support as many options as your want). I hope that helps.

```
/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width : 1200px) {

}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (max-width : 992px) {

}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {

}

/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {

}

/* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {

}
```

Comment: Thank you, Horacio!

I can add those to the additional CSS dialogue in the wordpress template customizer, or do I need to go into the editor itself? I'm hoping it's not the latter.